# Lucene for Java with PDFBox getting a nullpointer exception

Tags: java, jar, lucene, pdfbox

I'm frustrated with the **PDFBox API**.

I have done:

```
PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("text.pdf"));
PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
String s =  stripper.getText(pdfDocument);
pdfDocument.close();
```

but I'm getting a

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageNode.getAllKids(PDPageNode.java:194)
at org.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageNode.getAllKids(PDPageNode.java:182)
at org.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentCatalog.getAllPages(PDDocumentCatalog.java:226)
at org.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.writeText(PDFTextStripper.java:216)
at org.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.getText(PDFTextStripper.java:149)
at lucene.test.main(test.java:47)
```

at

```
String s =  stripper.getText(pdfDocument);
```

I have absolutely no idea why. Creating a PDF with the tutorial works great (http://pdfbox.apache.org/cookbook/textextraction.html). But this Text extraction does not. Already searched a lot but nothing helped.

Btw I still work with the "*pdfbox-0.7.3.jar*" because the new "*pdfbox-1.8.2.jar*" didn't work for me. Could this be the reason?

Thx for help.

PS: I'm getting the same error when using "stripper.writeText()"

Comment: Try : `File file = new File("text.pdf");` and then check `file.exists()`. Typical mistake is that the working path of program is in other place you think it is.

Comment: Changing text.pdf to some other name lead to a FilenotfoundException. So it should be working. But thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("text.pdf"));
```

just use

```
PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load("C:\TEMP\text.pdf");
```

I'm not sure why but it works for me now. Even with the old 0.7.3 of PDFBox.

Answer (score 1):

Add below external Jars:

1. pdfbox-1.3.1
2. commons-logging-1.2

Java Code:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.Splitter;   
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;  
import java.io.File;   
import java.io.IOException;   
import java.util.List;   
import java.util.Iterator;  

public class PdfSplitting {  

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {  

          File file = new File("D:/test.pdf");  
          PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);   

          Splitter splitter = new Splitter();  

          List<PDDocument>Pages = splitter.split(document);  

          Iterator<PDDocument>iterator = Pages.listIterator();  

    int i = 1;  
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {  
             PDDocument pd = iterator.next();  
    pd.save("D:/test"+ i++ +".pdf");  
          }  
          System.out.println("Pdf spitted successfully");  
    document.close();  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line

> PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("text.pdf"));

Specify the path for `text.pdf` there, ie along with the path.

Without knowing where the file resides how is the JVM supposed to create the file object, that is why the Exception occurs. Give the path over there, then you are good to go.

**Update**

It seems as a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-350) and has been fixed in later versions.

Comment: No this works fine. I have this text.pdf in the folder. The PDF exists. I know I should check the existence but there is no need for right now. This works 100%. It's just the getText line somehow.

Comment: @kwoxer The exception happens because `pdfDocument` is null. Have you tried giving the whole path with file name?

Comment: Yes of course I have also tested this. But it's no difference. The PDF is read correctly. By the way I created the PDF with Word and just one sentence in there. So the PDF is fine, too.

Comment: I think the problem might be a too old API maybe? But why does the new 1.8.2 not work for me?

Comment: @kwoxer This is a bug. What happens when you try the new versions?

Comment: Trying the pdfbox-1.8.2 I'm getting "PDDocument cannot be resolved to a type" and "PDFTextStripper cannot be resolved to a type". By the way: got the download from http://pdfbox.apache.org/downloads.html#recent pdfbox-1.8.2.jar 4.0MB

Comment: @kwoxer So you are not getting a Exception there. So most probably the old and new API is conflicting. Include all details by updating the question. With this much info We can't say the exact problem.

Comment: Right, I don't get an Exception. But I cleared the old APIs and just let in the new 1.8.2 there now. Restarted Eclipse and still got the "...cannot be..." warnings. I don't know which information you still need. Just say what I shall describe more.

Answer (score 0):

**for this always use For this always use pdfbox 1.8.6 and fop0.93**

PDDocument doc = null;
        try
        {
            doc = new PDDocument();
            PDPage page = new PDPage();
            doc.addPage(page);
            PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);

```
        PDFont pdfFont = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
        float fontSize = 25;
        float leading = 1.5f * fontSize;

        PDRectangle mediabox = page.findMediaBox();
        float margin = 72;
        float width = mediabox.getWidth() - 2*margin;
        float startX = mediabox.getLowerLeftX() + margin;
        float startY = mediabox.getUpperRightY() - margin;

        String text = "Hello sir finally PDF is created : thanks"; 
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        int lastSpace = -1;
        while (text.length() > 0)
        {
            int spaceIndex = text.indexOf(' ', lastSpace + 1);
            if (spaceIndex < 0)
            {
                lines.add(text);
                text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                String subString = text.substring(0, spaceIndex);
                float size = fontSize * pdfFont.getStringWidth(subString) / 1000;
                if (size > width)
                {
                    if (lastSpace < 0) // So we have a word longer than the line... draw it anyways
                        lastSpace = spaceIndex;
                    subString = text.substring(0, lastSpace);
                    lines.add(subString);
                    text = text.substring(lastSpace).trim();
                    lastSpace = -1;
                }
                else
                {
                    lastSpace = spaceIndex;
                }
            }
        }

        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.setFont(pdfFont, fontSize);
        contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(startX, startY);            
        for (String line: lines)
        {
            contentStream.drawString(line);
            contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(0, -leading);
        }
        contentStream.endText(); 
        contentStream.close();

         doc.save("E:\\document.pdf");
    }catch (Exception exp){
        logger.error("[GetInformation] email id is " +exp);

    }
    finally
    {
        if (doc != null)
        {
            try{
            doc.close();
            }catch (Exception expe){
                logger.error("[GetInformation] email id is " +expe);

            }
        }
    }
```